# urlencode within preg_replace, possible?

Tags: php, preg-replace, urlencode, urldecode, preg-replace-callback

Using following code to convert URLs within a text into real HTML links:

```
    $string = preg_replace("!(http|https|ftp|ftps)://([.]?[&;%#:=a-zA-Z0-9_/?-])*!", "<a href=\"away?to=\\0\">\\0</a>", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("!(^| |\n)(www([.]?[&;%#:=a-zA-Z0-9_/?-])+)!", "\\1<a href=\"away?to=www.\\2\">\\2</a>", $string);
```

Now there is a problem with URLs containing the **#** symbol (and perhaps other special chars too) and I would need the `urlencode()` function somehow within this `preg_replace()` function.

Any ideas?

Comment: have a look at `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: @Daan: Do you have an example for me regarding my code? Never worked with preg_replace_callback and haven't understood yet what I've read about how to use it with my code.

Comment: Where do you want to place `urlencode()` function?

Comment: @RahilWazir after the `away?to=`